# Последовательность действий при использовании директив

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется определенная директива app.js считывающая данные из атрибута info, имеется файл app.html, который определяет html код, вставляемый директивой в представление, имеется контроллер Main Controller.js, в котором хранятся мои данные. Хочу понять последовательность действий, когда директива уже записана в представлении. Index.html --> app.html --> MainControler.js или Index.html --> app.html --> app.js --> MainController.js?

Comment: что за последовательность действий имеется ввиду?

Comment: @grundy в какой последовательности ангуляр обращается к файлам

Comment: ангуляр к файлам вообще не обращается